# What is difference between creating twilio client using authentication token and combination of API key and API Secret with Account sid?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-node

I came across many twilio apis using account sid and authentication token to create twilio client (Refer 1 code) but I had even seen some twilio apis which uses account sid and api key with api secret to create twilio client (Refer 2 code). Wondering, what is difference between these?

Code 1 : Creating Twilio client using account sid and authenication token

```
     const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
```

Code 2 : Creating Twilio client using account sid and api key with api secret

```
     const Twilio = require("twilio");
     const client = new Twilio(API_KEY_SID, API_KEY_SECRET, {accountSid: ACCOUNT_SID});
```

Can anybody help me to understand the difference between these two different types of creating twilio client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation below provides the benefits of using API Keys rather than the Auth Token on the Account SID.

[REST API: API Keys](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/keys/api-key-resource)

"API Keys can be provisioned and revoked through the REST API or the Twilio Console. This provides a powerful and flexible primitive for managing access to the Twilio API."

If an account auth token is compromised, the process to change the auth token is via the console.

[Auth Tokens and How to Change Them (rotate credentials)](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136027-Auth-Tokens-and-How-to-Change-Them)

Comment: Thanks Alan, that's nice explaination. I had found the document of Twilio which describes the stuffs in detail. Here is the reference link
https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/your-request-to-twilio